# Getting a 403 error with Google Drive API v3, the request is not updated in Google API Metrics

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I am using Google Drive API to load videos in HTML5 video player.

```
<video id='drive-video' width='100%' height='100%' preload='metadata' playsinline>
  <source src='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<videoId>?alt=media&key=<api_key>' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

This works fine. However, when I am watching the video and doing different operations like going forward/backward etc., the video goes blank and I am unable to watch the video for about 15min. After that the video again plays and the same problem continues.

I tried to refresh the page and noticed that the GET request for the video using API is throwing a 403 error. I have checked the Google Chrome Network tab and did not see any response for this request.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2lu.png)
[Google API Quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0NJR.png)
[Google API Response Headers from Chrome Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF4XX.png)
[Google API Response from Chrome Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlUve.png)

Also, one weird thing is, when I get the 403 errors, I am not able to see any traffic in my Google Drive Metrics for this API key. It is as if the request is not being sent to Google.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Google drive is a file directory access api not a file play back api.  Put the video on Youtube.

Comment: We have a wide range to video sources and one of them is Google Drive. We do not own any videos. We have to make the player available for all the video sources.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the 403 error, are you hitting quotas? What does the error message say? Please add the rest of the player HTML too.

Comment: I am well under my quota. I have added a few screenshots. I am not getting any response message other than the error code.

Answer (score 0):

As @DaImTo points out Google drive is a file directory access API. You should host the videos on YouTube for optimal playback.

Comment: I know that YouTube is optimal for playback and we also have a YouTube player. Its just that some users store their videos in Google Drive wants to use them in our application. I am talking about this case. I think rather than suggestions I am looking for a possible solution. Thanks!